# Show progress in real time for promise function(s)

Tags: javascript, logging, promise, progress

Does anyone know how to log progress in real time or % of how much a promise has completed

for example, you have a function like this:

```
var promiseChain = function(){
  promise1()
    .then(function(result) { 
      return promise2();
    });
}
```

The promise code may contain an iterator firing API requests and response processing

Assuming there arent any exceptions and the script runs gracefully, how can I modify the code to watch the function like:
at the beginning `res.json('starting');`
in progress `res.json('55% complete...');`
at the end `res.json('promise resolved');`

I can use a `progress` variable in a higher scope and increment it in the promise code, but I'm looking for different ways to do it.

Related article on Observables
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress

Comment: Pass a callback that the async code will call after each step. There's nothing in promises that will help you here. (Due to their monadic nature, promises cannot know the number of steps)

Comment: No, XHRs `onprogress` event has nothing to do with this